# Where is the data from /info endpoint stored in the spring boot admin?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I want to send username and password of the spring boot applications to the spring boot admin in the /info endpoint. Now this data could be successfully sent to the spring boot admin and was displayed in the info column. Now I need to use this username/password data in the admin side. Question is whether the info data was stored in the admin side after the first automatic /info request, and how can I access this data? Because I don't want to request the info endpoint from the client side each time I use the data.
[image: spring boot admin info data]

Comment: What's the purpose of this all? I don't think you should publish secrets on your `/info` endpoint.

Comment: Because I want to add security in the client side. And the admin could get these encrypted username and password automatically and access all the protected client endpoints(I added a ZuulFilter to add basic authentication in every request to the endpoints). In this case, the clients could set different usernames and passwords.

Comment: @joshiste The username and password in the /info was encrypted by rsa public key and then decrypted in the admin side with private key. These decrypted usernames and passwords were stored in a hashmap. The admin UI only displays the encrypted username and password. Not like the picture in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data from `/info` isn't stored on the admin server.